# How to write a yii mongodb query with OR condition?

Tags: mongodb

How can I write a query in yii mongodb with `OR` condition.
For example, in SQL we can write the query like below

```
select * from tablename where fieldname = value1 or fieldname1 = value1
```

How can I write this in yii mongodb as i have to check whether a particular value is available in two fields in mongodb collection.

Comment: Use the [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/) operator.

Comment: read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_or

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using YiiMongoDBSuite (YMDS), lack of `$or` support is noted as a [current limitation of that extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/#hh5):

> In it's current incarnation, This extension does NOT work with the "$or" criteria operator. When we get it working we will remove this line and add an example.

Unfortunately the YMDS extension is not actively maintained, and does not support the full complement of features available in the MongoDB query language.

A recommended alternative would be to use the officially supported [MongoDB PHP driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php):

```
<?php
    $cursor = $collection->find(
        array(
            '$or' => array(
                "fieldname" => "value1",
                "fieldname1" => "value2"
            )
        )
    );
?>
```